# can we set different realm configuration for different module?

Tags: android, realm

I have main android project that uses another android module. In main android project am getting real instance with some configuration like as.

```
realm = Realm.getInstance(someConfig());
```

Am initing Realm from main app Application class, as follows

```
Realm.init(Context);
```

In my module when I try to call following line it shows error.

```
Realm db = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

Error:

```
error Wrong key used to decrypt Realm.
W/System.err: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong key used to decrypt Realm.
```

Answer (score 2):

1.) I genuinely think that a *library* that relies on having its own RealmConfiguration to be set as ***the*** "default configuration" is heavily intrusive. So library code should use `Realm.getInstance(configuration)`.

2.) If you want the configurations to refer to different files, you might want to set a different name using `new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("somename.realm")/*...*/`.

Comment: I tried creating custom configuration with diff name(message.realm). after i called Realm.getInstance(configuration). but no use. still error

Comment: You should probably create the custom configuration **before** you open a Realm with the given configuration...?

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to parent class which extends Application/MutlidexApplication class or where ur intializing Realm:

```
Realm.init(Parent.this);
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name(AppConstants.DATABASE_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(2)
                // .migration(new DBMigration())
               // .migration(new Migration())
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
        Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```